# Why does REDIS key keep expiring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm using REDIS to store an integer value which represents the version of a document.  In my code, the only calls to REDIS are the following:

```
 def get_document

   ...
   version = REDIS.get("version").to_i
   ...

 end
```

and

```
 def publish_document

    ...
    REDIS.incr("version")
    ...

 end
```

The idea is every time we publish the document, its version number goes up.  It has to always go up, never down.  When we retrieve the document, we'll know which version we're on.

The problem is that every now and then, the version number goes back down to 0, which means the REDIS key "version" got deleted somehow (since nil.to_i => 0). But nowhere in my code do I delete "version" nor did I sent an expiration date.

Does anyone know what's going on?  Do REDIS keys have a default expiration date?  Or is the REDIS server getting reset without me knowing?

Comment: Do you have Redis configured with a memory limit and an LRU purge or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Redis keys do not have a default expiration date.

Are you sure there is nothing deleting your key?

Can you check if your Redis server gets restarted?
Are you using any form of persistance on the Redis data set?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Matteo.  I scoured the entire project and the above snippets are the only mentions of the "version" key.  So it's definitely not being deleted.  If the REDIS server gets restarted does that delete all the keys?

Comment: If you are not using any persistance and the server restarts, yes your data set is gone. You can find more info on Redis's persistance in the doc http://redis.io/topics/persistence